# Find and edit line in a text file

Tags: c#, file, edit, streamwriter

How could I find a specific book id, ex = 11 (with `\t+` pattern)

```
book ID\t   Book Titlte\t       Author\t              Edition\t   DueDate\t   Borrower ID\n   
    10\t    Java Performance\t  Charlie Hunt, Binu John\t   1\t -\t -\n
    11\t    Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases\t  Joshun Bloch, Neal Gafter\t 1\t 23/04/2015\t    100002\n     //// this one
    12\t    Real-Time C++\t Chris Kormanyos\t   1\t 23/05/2015\t    100020\n
    13\t    Secure Coding in C and C++\t    Robert Seacord\t    2\t -\t -
```

the DueDate and Borrower ID became "-"

```
book ID\t   Book Titlte\t       Author\t              Edition\t   DueDate\t   Borrower ID\n   
    10\t    Java Performance\t  Charlie Hunt, Binu John\t   1\t -\t -\n
    11\t    Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases\t  Joshun Bloch, Neal Gafter\t 1\t -\t -\n ///////////became this one 
    12\t    Real-Time C++\t Chris Kormanyos\t   1\t 23/05/2015\t    100020\n
    13\t    Secure Coding in C and C++\t    Robert Seacord\t    2\t -\t -\n
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean `the DueDate and Borrower ID became "-"`, what has the due date got to with the ID. Essentially it seems you just want to iterate the lines collection of the file and remove one of them if the ID is 11? So just ReadLines and use a for loop to run a split string. Write every line back into the file except the one that matches. And obviously stop splitting after you have your match. Or alternatively you could (possibly) read the whole file into memory and do a string replace via indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

There are, as always a multitude of ways of doing this, all of which depend entirely upon the context of the problem. A very simple (naive?) way would be as follows:

```
 var idToFind = 11;
 var s = File.ReadAllText(fPath);
 var start = s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine + idToFind.ToString() + '\t');
 var end = s.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, start + 1);
 var line = s.Substring(start, end - start);
 var lineFields = line.Split("\t".ToCharArray());
 lineFields[4]= "-";
 lineFields[5]= "-";
 var newContent = s.Replace(line, lineFields.Join("\t"));
 File.WriteAllText(fPath, newContent);
```